# How can I obtain an &A reference from a Rc<RefCell<A>>?

Tags: reference, rust, smart-pointers, borrowing

I have design issue that I would like solve with safe Rust that I haven't been able to find a viable solution. I can't use a `RefCell` because you can't get a & reference to the data, only `Ref` / `RefMut`.

Here is a [simplified example with irrelevant fields / methods removed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=621c2b77ea2b2785e9ae95960427fb2e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct LibraryStruct {}
impl LibraryStruct {
    fn function(&self, _a: &TraitFromLibrary) {}
}

trait TraitFromLibrary {
    fn trait_function(&self, library_struct: LibraryStruct);
}

// I don't want to copy this, bad performance
struct A {
    // fields...
}

impl TraitFromLibrary for A {
    fn trait_function(&self, library_struct: LibraryStruct) {
        // custom A stuff
    }
}

// B manipulates A's in data
struct B {
    data: Vec<A>,
}

struct C {
    // This type doesn't have to be & for solution. C just needs immutable access
    a: Rc<RefCell<A>>,
}

impl<'a> TraitFromLibrary for C {
    fn trait_function(&self, library_struct: LibraryStruct) {
        // custom C stuff

        // Takes generic reference &, this is why Ref / RefCell doesn't work
        library_struct.function(&self.a.borrow());
    }
}

// B and C's constructed in Container and lifetime matches Container
// Container manipulates fields b and c
struct Container {
    b: B,
    c: Vec<C>,
}

fn main() {}
```

I would be able to solve this with `Rc<RefCell<A>>` but I am being restricted from the library requiring `&A`.

This produces the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::cell::Ref<'_, A>: TraitFromLibrary` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:33:33
   |
33 |         library_struct.function(&self.a.borrow());
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TraitFromLibrary` is not implemented for `std::cell::Ref<'_, A>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `TraitFromLibrary`
```

Comment: I was trying to be vague about C's field type because it can not be `&'a A`. Struct B and C exist at the same time in Container and there would be a mutability issue as there would be an immutable reference in C and B needs mutability at times.

Comment: Ok, so ideally you want `C`'s `a` to be a `RefCell`, but that won't work with the library function?

Comment: Yes because you cannot get a &A from RefCell only Ref<A> / RefMut<A>

Comment: I just made some changes, which I think communicates what you were getting at. And I think the answer is to just `Rc<RefCell<A>>` and then pass it to the library function as `library_struct.function(&self.a.borrow());`

Comment: This works because both `Ref` implements `Deref`. If a function accepts a `&`-reference, then you can pass a reference to any type that implements `Deref`, as in [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3f32df819027cfe84183cbd34bf42cc7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a function has an argument which is a of type `&A`, then you can call it with a reference to any type that dereferences to `A`, which includes things like `&Ref<A>`. The concept of one type dereferencing to another is captured by the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait. This is also the reason why a function that accepts `&str` can be called with `&String` (`String: Deref<Target = str>`).

So, if you keep `a` as a `Rc<RefCell<A>>`, you can fix your code quite easily like this:

```
library_struct.function(&*self.a.borrow());
```

Note that this dereferences `A` and then *reborrows* it so that it can be coerced to a trait object.